# how to display grouped listview with gridlines?

Tags: c#, winforms, c++-cli

i created a listview with many groupds inside     meanwhile  I set listview.view=details and set gridlines=true  but I couldn't find the gridlines in the listview when the listview was displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think gridlines are supported when used with groups.

Comment: Can i Set the OwnerDraw property to true and draw the gridlines by myself?